# How to store user defined objects using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I was able to do this in ServiceStack.redis by using,

```
IRedisTypedClient<ObjectName> myObj = redisClient.As<ObjectName>();
```

But I couldn't find any examples to do this in StackExchange.Redis.

Do I have to Serialize to JSON and then store them?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At the current time, SE.Redis does not attempt to offer serialisation - there are simply too many different ways of doing that. I'm rather of the opinion that the library should do one thing, not 7. It should be possible to add any hybrid serialisation etc concerns simply by extension methods or other plumbing/wrapping code, choosing any serialisation strategy you choose, and any library you choose.

Comment: So the solution is another layer of abstraction?  I appreciate that StackExchange.Redis is a fairly bare-bones client and other concerns should be implemented as extensions.  Any thoughts on https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions?

Also, thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 11):

Simplest solution will be use json/binary/other serialization. More complex but more native - using redis ["hashes" data type](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes).

In first case i prefer **protobuf** library (it included by default to  [StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Protobuf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Protobuf/1.1.9) nuget package). But you can use json/binary/xml serialization if you need.

There is a good performance report about them all : https://medium.com/@maximn/serialization-performance-comparison-xml-binary-json-p-ad737545d227

Answer (score 6):

Example: Create helper function sample below, used JSON SerializeObject/DeSerializeObject before get/set.But this solution has the limitation object size can't not over Int32.MaxNumber ( 2,147,483,647 is 2Gb ).

> Sample Code

```
    public static void SetData<T>(string key, T data)
    {
        using (var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379"))
        {
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            json_serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

            db.StringSet(key, json_serializer.Serialize(data));
            redis.Close();
        }
    }

    public static T GetData<T>(string key)
    {
        using (var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379"))
        {
            try
            {
                IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
                var res = db.StringGet(key);

                redis.Close();
                if (res.IsNull)
                    return default(T);
                else
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation you shouldn't use `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect` each time you want to access the data. You should store the connection and use the light weight `GetDatabase()` each time.

Comment: No need to call .close() on the main var of a using block.

Comment: This works fine when you only need to connect occasionally to save/get some values, so storing an active connections is useless.